# Storing string value in java

Tags: java, android, string, sharedpreferences

I am developing a simple android app.In that i want to store a string value like "1_2_5_7_12_".After that want to split this string and have to get the numbers.How to store this string.Sharedpreference or any other help?

Comment: Have you tried anything by yourself ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  String s = "1_2_5_7_12_";

  SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  Editor edit = preferences.edit();
  edit.putString("pref_str", s); 
  edit.commit();//storing
  // Retrieve
  String pref_numstr =  preferences.getString("pref_str", "n/a");
  ar = pref_numstr.split("_");
  System.out.println(ar.length);
```

Comment: String pref_numstr =  preferences.getString("pref_str", "n/a"); in this line what is "n/a"?

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string :

```
String myString = "1_2_5_7_12_";
String numbers[] = myString.split("_");
int num[] = new int[numbers.length];
int i=0;
for(String s : numbers){
   num[i] = Integer.parseInt(s);
   i++;
}
```

So now the array `num` will contain integers in that string.

Answer (score 1):

try as using [Pattern.compile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for split String to Array:

```
   String str = "1_2_5_7_12_";
   String[] strarray=Pattern.compile("-").split(str);
```

and for storing or retrieve value from SharedPreferences see

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Answer (score 0):

to save

```
SharedPreference.edit().putString(value, default).commit()
```

to get value

```
SharedPreference.getString(value, default)
```

to split the string

```
String.split("_") to split
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually it's gonna be a string, so i do not see any problem to store it in Sharedpreference . And you can split it as in @Shreya Shah's response

Answer (score 0):

you can do by this..

```
            final SharedPreferences pref1 = getSharedPreferences("My_App", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref1.edit();

            editor.putString("str", "yourString");
            editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Save like this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor prefsEditor = prefs .edit();
prefsEditor.putString("myString", "1_2_5_7_12");
prefsEditor.commit();
```

and retrieve like this:

```
String str= prefs.getString("myString", "");
```

after that you can split your string simply by doing

```
String[] strArr = str.split("_");
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code ....

```
public static  ArrayList<String> strDRIVERS = new ArrayList<String>();
String DNAME="1_2_5_7_12";
if(DNAMES.length()>0){
  String[] arr_drivers = DNAMES.split(",");
  for(String sx : arr_drivers){
    strDRIVERS.add(sx);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For saving string you can use SharedPreferences or string.xml file. For splitting the string

```
String text = "1_2_5_7_12_";
String[] splits = text.split("_");
```